# How to know, which kernels have some commit applied to them?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

Suppose, I want to know, in which kernel versions some commit is in their code. How can I do it?

Comment: I think the question is: in the Linux kernel history I see this commit which fixes my issue, which kernel version do I have to install to make use of it. Correct?

Comment: Usually, distributions are patching their kernel. Then you should look into the source package of the kernel for your distribution.

Comment: as seen from the answer, this looks to me like a real question with quite a precise answer, I don't think it should be closed.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `git describe --contains`.

For example,

```
% git show -p c5efa5fc91f1f6d1d47e65f39e7ec6d1157c777d
commit c5efa5fc91f1f6d1d47e65f39e7ec6d1157c777d
Author: Trond Myklebust <Trond.Myklebust@netapp.com>
Date:   Wed May 26 08:42:11 2010 -0400

    NFS: Ensure that we mark the inode as dirty if we exit early from commit


% git describe --contains c5efa5fc91f1f6d1d47e65f39e7ec6d1157c777d
v2.6.35-rc1~43^2~1
```

Comment: So this is where the commit is introduced? What does "~43^2~1" mean?

Answer (score 0):

You can list all tags, and there corresponding committish, and its commit date by:

```
FORMAT=$'\e[47m%h\e[0m\e[1;45m%d\e[0m \e[1;31m[%an]\e[0m %s \e[1;34m%ar\e[0m'
git tag | xargs -l git log --oneline -n1 --format="$FORMAT"
```

The output:

```
....
b6fd41e (v3.1-rc6) [Linus Torvalds] Linux 3.1-rc6 2 months ago
d93dc5c (v3.1-rc7) [Linus Torvalds] Linux 3.1-rc7 9 weeks ago
a102a9e (v3.1-rc8) [Linus Torvalds] Linux 3.1-rc8 8 weeks ago
976d167 (v3.1-rc9) [Linus Torvalds] Linux 3.1-rc9 7 weeks ago
1ea6b8f (v3.2-rc1) [Linus Torvalds] Linux 3.2-rc1 2 weeks ago
cfcfc9e (v3.2-rc2) [Linus Torvalds] Linux 3.2-rc2 7 days ago
```

To know which commits are included in 3.2-rc2, you can type:

```
git log --oneline --graph --format="$FORMAT" 1ea6b8f..cfcfc9e
```

and see the output:

```
* cfcfc9e (v3.2-rc2) [Linus Torvalds] Linux 3.2-rc2 7 days ago
*   101041c [Linus Torvalds] Merge branch 'iommu/fixes' of git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/joro/
|\  
| * 08f2e63 [Ming Lei] iommu: omap: Fix compile failure 2 weeks ago
*   5870b2c [Linus Torvalds] Merge branch 'fixes' of git://git.linaro.org/people/triad/linux-pinctrl 7 days ag
|\  
| * 45f034e [Linus Walleij] pinctrl: hide subsystem from the populace 2 weeks ago
| * e0e2075 [Barry Song] pinctrl: fix "warning: 'struct pinctrl_dev' declared inside parameter list" 4 weeks a
*   642ba5e [Linus Torvalds] Merge branch 'for-linus' of git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/paulg/l
|\  
....
```

Well, though `v3.2-rc1..v3.2-rc2` does also work, I prefer this way because sometimes the tag name may include two dots.